# Convergence to Gaussian with infinitesimal condition with relation to Levy Triple.

Tags: probability

I have posted this question before under the title "Uniform infinitesimality Condition and convergence in distribution to Gaussian distribution".

I managed to find something related to this question in the book "Probability Theory" by  By S. R. S. Varadhan.

http://books.google.com.sg/books?id=zAZJdAcDrKsC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=levy%20measure&f=false

At page 64, in the application part, he did mention about the relationship between uniform infinitesimality condition and Levi Triple.

Suppose a triangular array of iid random variables $(X_{n,i})_{1\leq i\leq n}$ satisfying the uniform infinitesimality condition

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}P(|X_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0$$

If the distribution of $A_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{n,i}$ converges in distribution to a limit $\mu$, then we know that $\mu$ is infinitely divisible and by the Levy-Khintchine representation, admits a Levy Triple $(M,{\sigma}^2,a)$, where $M$ is the Levy measure, ${\sigma}^2>0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, the book mentions that the limiting distribution $\mu$ is Gaussian $$\iff M\equiv0$$$$\iff{\lim_{n\to \infty}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,i}-a_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0-----(*) $$ when $a_{n,i}$ is the centering needed if necessary.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{i}|a_{n,i}|=0$, then $$Condition\ (*)\iff{\lim_{n\to \infty}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0$$

I guess that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{i}|a_{n,i}|=0$ has something to do with to the infinitesimality condition $\lim_{n\to \infty}\max_{1\leq i\leq n}P(|X_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0$. Hence the last $``\iff"$ does make some sense heuristically.

However, I was puzzled by the second $``\iff"$, which is $$M\equiv0 \iff \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,i}-a_{n,i}|>\epsilon)=0\ \forall\epsilon>0$$

All I know is that the Levy measure $M$ has something to do with compounded Poisson Process, the ${\sigma}^2$ is related to Gaussian and $a$ corresponds to a shift.

Kindly help in explaining the details.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you read the example I gave in your precedent question? It seems that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(|X_{n,i}| > \epsilon) = 0$ is not sufficient to get the limit distribution is gaussian

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I have read your answer to my earlier post. But after that, I found this section in the book which is almost exactly the same as the question that I have posed. I intend to understand what the author is trying to say, as he sounds as if it is a trivial matter. Anyway, thank you for answering my former question.:)

Comment: Do you know why the second $\Longleftrightarrow$ holds and how to choose $a_{n,i}$.

Answer (score 0):

The question should have one more condition: $\mu$ is non-degenarate. In this case, these two conditions are equivalent.